# Reloading featherlight.js target div content

Tags: featherlight.js

I am trying to do an ajax call and then load that information into a featherlight box.  Before doing the ajax call, I am calling featherlight to put up a box saying create report......  I could not get the manual featherlight box to work.  It would always give me a blank box.  I decided to add a hidden div that has that featherlight click example.  I then change the innerhtml of the target div and do $("#lk").click(); and it opens whatever I put in it as it should.  When the report comes back, I update the innerhtml, do the example current.close() and then do the $("#lk").click(); again.  This works fine, but it flashes.  I tried changing the innerhtml of the target div, but that does not update until I do the $("#lk").click();.  It there a way to change the innerhtml and have the box resize vs closing and opening it again?

By the way, great function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the featherlight lightbox is making a copy of the hidden div.  did you try to update the featherlight copy of the div directly?  looks like it making a div.featherlight then a div.featherlight-content then your original content should be inside